# Pear Install - Console/Getopt.php not found

Tags: pear

I'm installing Pear on my web hosting using go-pear.php and I get this error:

```
Bootstrapping Installer...................
Bootstrapping PEAR5.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping PEAR.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Archive/Tar.php............(remote) ok
Bootstrapping Console/Getopt.php............(remote) Not Foundok
```

I have:

```
$bootstrap_files = array(
    'PEAR5.php'            => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR5.php',
    'PEAR.php'             => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/pear-core/master/PEAR.php',
    'Archive/Tar.php'      => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Archive_Tar/master/Archive/Tar.php',
    'Console/Getopt.php'   => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Console_Getopt/trunk/Console/Getopt.php',
);
```

Right enough, the last URL returns 404, does not exist.  I've looked everywhere, anyone know what is the correct URL that goes there?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? We recently changed the minimum PHP version to 5.4.0 in Console_Getopt

Comment: Where did you get `go-pear.php` from, and which command do you use to install pear on your hoster? Which PHP version does your hoster have?

Comment: PHP version 5.4.36, got it form http://pear.php.net/go-pear, I just use URL (Ex: mysite.com/pear/go-pear.php. Thank you both for helping.

Comment: Try to use `pear.php.net/go-pear.phar` - I'm not sure if go-pear (without .phar) is still supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [restored the "trunk" branch](https://github.com/pear/Console_Getopt/tree/trunk), so downloading should work again. Sorry for the fuzz.

Apart from this, use the `go-pear.phar` file instead of the `go-pear` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to change the url. the current url does not exist anymore. Try the following URL:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Console_Getopt/master/Console/Getopt.php

Comment: No the URL is correct I believe, it just returns a 404.